# Android Studio weird error

Tags: android, android-studio

so I'm following this online course and while I was doing an exercise/project I had this error "Cannot resolve symbol R", now I've had it before and could easily fix it by chosing the clean/rebuild/synchorinze etc options however it doesn't work this time, I've had a look at both the XML and java code and even copied and pasted the final exercise code just in case with no results, now the funny/not so funny part is that those who've tried the project that I've uploaded had no problem making it run, I've tried doing a complete and clean reinstall of Android Studio as well just in case, if anybody knows any fix or reason why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried alt+enter on R?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package statement at the top is correct. If I remember correctly this happens sometimes when you create an activity in a package you nested in your main package.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tip in another website, but I can't refer the link here. The following tip is from Ron McLeod in the coderanch.com :

"R is a generated class.  You may need to manually import it in to your code.

The R class should be in the top-level package for application.  For example, in my case the top-level package for the application is: com.mcleodnet.hflink, so my code imports: import com.mcleodnet.hflink.R

[image](https://coderanch.com/i/3208245/android-generated-R.png)

package com.mcleodnet.hflink.ui;

import com.mcleodnet.hflink.R;

...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements UIMessageReceiver,

StationDialogListener, ChannelDialogListener {

...

channelMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_channel_green);

}

Post by: Norm Radder , Rancher

Aug 22, 2017 13:47:46

The IDE takes care of building the R.java file.  Often an error in an XML file will cause the IDE not to generate the R.java file.  Check all the xml files for errors."

Answer (score 0):

Do check the import statements.
If any of them imports `R`, remove that one and rebuild your project. It might help since you copy pasted the code, the imports might not suit your project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the import statement of R at the top of your file. It must be of the form **com.example.app.R** (i.e, your package name followed by the letter R). If it is not, remove this import and import it again. No need to rebuild or clean your project

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Android Studio error. One of the most effective ways I've found to deal with it is to close out of Android Studio, find your .AndroidStudio[version] generated file and delete it.

Then reopen Android Studio and go through the setup prompts. You shouldn't get the error now.

Comment: Thanks to all comments, apologies for the late reply but I've only been notified now, I've went onwards from that problem with other projects but thanks.